# TextField() does not show the begin of content when has a lot of text

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

How Can I force TextField to show a specific part of text on it,  when its having multiple lines?  Now it seems to show just last line always without user interaction

Comment: In reply to your comment: scrollV *is* for lines, set it to five and it displays line five and below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [scrollV property](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#scrollV). Set it to zero and your text should scroll back up to show the start of the text, set it to [maxScrollV](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#maxScrollV) to show the last line or set it to any value inbetween those two to show a line of your choice.

Comment: I like to show a specific ROW; is this possible, is there API to count what ScrollV needs to be based on text position/row?